# How to specify servlet error-page per path

Tags: servlets

web.xml's `<error-page>` allows a developer to specify what to return to client in case of some error (either HTTP status or java exception).

But I have 2 different 404 error pages, per locale.

My web application is structured so that all resources for locale A is under path `/a/`; resources for locale B under path `/b/`.

I'd like to have a localized error page for 404 when trying to access pages under each locale (to be clear, trying to access `/a/some-undefined-resource` should return 404 + an error page localized for locale A).

Given other limitations, it is not really possible to deploy 2 separate applications, a.war and b.war for each locale.

How can I serve an error page that depends on original resource requested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended giving up the idea to use `<error-page>` to serve my SPA and used the [urlrewrite filter](https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to rewrite URLs to either `/a/index.html` or `/b/index.html`.

The downside is that now I have two places to edit when I add new routes inside my SPA:

- angular routes (`app-routing.module.ts`), and
- `urlrewrite.xml`.

Besides, if I add a new locale in the future, I'll need to add a new set of rules to cover all my routes.

Also I don't know how this filter will impact my site's performance. Since it is a low traffic project, I'll keep it this way until I find a better solution.

There is an upside too: now those - otherwise legal - requests are served with status 200, and really missing resources are signaled with 404 and no default content included.